# Incorrect data and time stamp

Tags: carto, datetime

I am using the following select statement to enter the a record in a cartodb database.

```sql
INSERT INTO catch (
  site_code, 
  have_catch, 
  fishtype1, 
  fishtype2, 
  fishtype3, 
  fishtype4, 
  fishtype5, 
  number_of_species, 
  **catch_date**, 
  fisherman_id
) 
VALUES (
 '$siteCode',      
 1,
 '$fishtype1',
 '$fishtype2',
 '$fishtype3',
 '$fishtype4',
 '$fishtype5', 
 $numbFish, 
 **now()**, 
 '$fishermanId'
);
```

The catch_date, created_at and updated_at dates being written is a day ahead if the actual date.  E.g. 2016-03-31 instead of 2016-03-30.

Any idea as to the cause?

This is a recent issue that seems to have started after I upgraded to the latest version of cartodb.js.

Also, the data is being written to a database in my cartodb cloud account.

I'm not sure as to the time zone.

Comment: In what time zone does your data exist? Does the local browser exist in a different time zone?

Comment: @Vince  The data is being collected in the Caribbean

Comment: Please **edit the question** in response to requests for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Is it UTC?
Current UTC time: 3:41 AM Thursday, March 31, 2016
My local time: 8:41 PM Wednesday, March 30, 2016

[Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)

Answer (score 0):

Once you know in which time zone the data was collected ([here](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/caribbean) you have a list of all the Caribbean time zones), you can update your date column with the following SQL query:

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME
SET DATE_COLUMN = DATE_COLUMN AT TIME ZONE 'CODE'
```